# Why some volumes are already created inside docker engine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Whenever I run the below command:

```
docker volume ls
```

I can see some volumes already created in my docker engine.

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     5df9458932cd504e10b2b37856c434cbdf3876733684b100cbf390c965ac9581
local     6f7037bc33861a5e42a9f8bcd699f8184ff1916a297a718ccc4df5f369d07530
local     8a86c462020f35f1051b47c48555228a1df359251f2496c32ed45a9081bb1872
local     85ed838d2e081eddc672fd8ddb15bbb3eecc73adb270678c98b7c50a03ecb2fc
```

1. Why are those volume created ?
2. How can I find for what purpose they exists ?

Comment: On what system do you see these volumes? I don't get such an output neither on Linux nor on Windows (Docker Desktop).

Comment: @Tekki they occurred because someone created container like this " -v ~/data : /data "... as there was no name for the volume and only path provided, the reason I got such result :) Someone cleared it out below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you started a Docker container with a volume that doesn't have a name or host mount point, Docker will create a unique name for them. These [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#more-details-about-mount-types) briefly mention anonymous volumes like this. Most likely, a Dockerfile had a `VOLUME` section and wasn't run with a corresponding `--mount` or `-v` flag to bind some local volume to the container's volume.

Also see [this devops stack exchange answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/why-are-unnamed-volumes-created-when-docker-compose-up-is-run-and-do-these-dou).

Here's an example of when an anonymous volume is created:

Dockerfile with anonymous volumes:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

VOLUME ["/root", "/test"]
```

Building/running container without mounting or otherwise naming the `/root`, `/test` volumes:

```sh
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME

$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run -it --rm -d --name volume-test  test:latest sh

$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     5b332abd25b77c1ac324a0e3c00dc9a554cfe80c996a20bd77ef10c35c8ef98a
local     05c903f47f3f3666e03ee06154ff54b23547a5cc65750ca18bb40be40ed4049c
local     6f595aada6ae7c9fb16831996c2bdd8d652bec55a7cedf96afef95aec8f4e6e1
local     7f54c9dbbec46acc5a843499c65a50e23a78baa884facd026704d0dcb0362c9e
local     47a791197d6164757b015df1e2aba48bac3999720ead6b5981820a3aaece4113
local     214155fe63200cc859c1eddd2b31aa990fd6eb7c8614aa02bd8b57690b0fe53e
```

Of course, you can always inspect the volumes to try to find out where they came from but this may or may not be useful for you:

```
docker inspect 5b332abd25b77c1ac324a0e3c00dc9a554cfe80c996a20bd77ef10c35c8ef98a
```